# Can MapsterMapper specify to map only some fields?

Tags: c#, .net, mapper

Below is the sample code

```cs
public People{
   public int Age{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string Address{get;set;}
}

public PeopleDto{
  public int Age{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public string Address{get;set;}
}
```

Now, I want to map the `Age` and `Name` fields, while the `Address` field keeps the default value,I would like to have a function like the following available:

```cs
var config= TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.Default.Config.Clone();
config
.ForType<People, PeopleDto>()
.IncludeFields(src=>src.Age,src=>src.Name)//This method does not currently exist, here is just an example
.MaxDepth(2);
```

Can this be done please?

I searched for relevant information but did not find any usable information.

Answer (score 0):

it's fixed

```cs
var config= TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.Default.Config.Clone();
config
.ForType<People, PeopleDto>()
.IgnoreMember((m, s) => s == MemberSide.Source)
.Map(d => d.Name, s => s.Name)
.Map(d => d.Age, s => s.Age);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).